# How to add extra dependency to maven Web Application Resource (WAR) project to maven repository with NetBeans?

Tags: maven, tomcat, netbeans, jar, maven-dependency

I'm having an issue adding a "catalina-6.0.26.jar" dependency (.jar file) to my maven repository, so that it will show up in the "Add Dependency" window of the query text box in the NetBeans IDE.
For some reason, the maven repository does not seem to allow me to add any  extra dependencies outside of what is already in my .m2/repository directory.
The link below shows is a screen shot of the limited dependencies I have access to when using the query in the text-box:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLhDo.png)

The pom.xml is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.proxysecure</groupId>
<artifactId>proxy-web</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>proxy-web</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: can you show pom.xml

Comment: I added the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `<dependencies>` section in your pom.xml and save.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.26</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Run `mvn clean install`

Comment: Welcome:). Can you accept the answer in that cas @CarsonGedeus